# Find the generating function for the sequence $a_{n}=2n+1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the generating function for the sequence $a_{n}=2n+1$, then for the sequence of partial sums, and finally, find a formula for the sum of the sequence of partial sums.

What I have so far:
$$\begin{array}\\
a_{n}&=&a_{n-1}+2
\\a_{0}&=&1 \\
 a_{1}&=&3  \\ 
a_{2}&=&5 \\ 
a_{3}&=&7 \\
&\vdots&
\end{array}$$

This is the sequence of odd numbers.

We have learned that the generating function, $$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}\cdot x^n$$

So, would $$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2n+1)\cdot x^n\;?$$

I am pretty confused about what else to do for this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(n%3D0,infinity,(2n%2B1)x%5En)

Comment: Your approach is correct, but this sum can be calculated, if it converges (for $|x|<1$, this is the case). The sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ is well known, to get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot x^n$$ differentiate both sides of the above equation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
g(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2n+1)\cdot x^n
=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n
=2x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Hence
$$
g(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Further
$$
\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{g(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(2k+1)\cdot x^n.
$$
At this point use the fact that for $m\geq 1$
$$
(1-x)^{-m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+n-1}{n}x^n
$$
to extract the coefficients.